# "Waiting" pronunciation like "Wedding"?

Tags: pronunciation

Is there any dialect of American English, where "**Waiting**" is pronounced as "**Wedding**"?

Comment: Many Americans reduce /t/ to /d/ in such contexts, so their ***waiting*** might be close (or even *equal*) to their ***wading***. But if what you hear there is ***wedding***, I think almost certainly *that same speaker* would enunciate the actual word ***wedding*** very differently. I don't think there would be any native Anglophones for whom ***waiting*** and ***wedding*** are actually ***homophones*** (that sound identical).

Comment: No, waiting is pronounced: waitin', no g. And wedding can also be: weddin', no g.

Comment: @Lambie The last phoneme in both the words is /ŋ/. It not clear, but it appears that you're placing some emphasis on this. Would someone assume from your transcription of *waiting* as "waitin'" that it is to be pronounced with a *g* sound? In my view, your transcription, "waitin'", with the apostrophe and all, denotes an entirely different pronunciation, associated with e.g., Southern American English dialects, where this final consonant is in fact an [n]. This isn't *generally* the case in AmE.

Comment: @userr2684291 There is no dialect of American English where "waiting" is pronounced as "wedding". What does exist is the dropping of the g in both. And it's not just southern, fyi.

Comment: I second (or third) the answer: **no**. There are variations in the pronunciation of both words but there is no overlap in those variations.